# How to manipulate browsing history?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-history

Once in my Web app people hit a button that triggers a (bootstrap) MODAL so the history doesn't change, so some users hit the BACK button of the BROWSER (thinking to close the modal or go back to the main page) but they get away from my app instead of closing the modal. So I'm thinking in something like this:

1. When the user is at the main page, I set the history with a URL with a param with a value of: store, so next time that I check for it I can close all modals.

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "1", "/?action=store");
```

2. When the person hits the button that triggers the modal I change the state to the modal state

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "2", "/?action=modal");
```

In this way I want to open the modal and If a person hits the BACK button the history MUST find the action=store and closes the modal. It works but when I hit the BACK button the URL changes but it NOT refreshes or navigates to it.

How can I do this? *PS. The code blocks aren't working, please edit them as code.

Comment: *some users hit the BACK button of the BROWSER (thinking to close the modal or go back to the main page)* Really? Do you have a prominent "Close" button in the modal?

Comment: You can use ``` to do code blocks.

Comment: I have control over what happens inside the web app, but I have no control over the Native Navigation buttons at the bottom of most Smartphones and at the browsers, so people get confuse and use these buttons (mostly the Back button) to close the modal but instead they go back to google or to the last visited URL. That's what I want to control in someway to keep then in my Web app.

Comment: You could use `onBeforeUnload` to ensure the user wants to leave the page.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like your are trying to treat a symptom and not the disease. This shouldn't be an issue at all if you design the UI properly.

Comment: Ok, let's assume that all my users understand that these buttons work differently in web apps and apps and let them to go away from my website in some way. Thanks buddie.

Comment: You should be designing your UI differently for different viewports. I'm not trying to be rude or sarcastic. I'm telling you that you are solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Yeah man, you are right. I’m just going to wait for some another approach to evaluate my options. Thanks for your time.

Comment: may help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

Comment: Could use hashes instead. Browser navigation between the same page but different hashes doesn't cause a reload and you can catch this change by watching for `hashchange` events.